# iOS - deleting all entries containing a key on all NSDictionaries stored inside a main NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a main NSMutableDictionary that contains a collection of others NSMutableDictionary.

The thing goes like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *subDict1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     obj1, @"name",
     obj2, @"color",
    nil];

NSMutableDictionary *subDict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     obj3, @"name",
     obj4, @"color",
     obj5, @"address",
     obj6, @"phone",
     obj7, @"color",
     obj8, @"parent",
    nil];

NSMutableDictionary *subDict3 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     obj0, @"name",
     obj9, @"parent",
     objA, @"site",
     objB, @"surname",
     objC, @"label",
    nil];
```

These sub dictionaries may have different number of entries and the keys may vary. Some may have keys with the same name.

They are stored in a main dictionary like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mainDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    subDict1, @"1",
    subDict3, @"3",
    subDict2, @"2",
    nil];
```

I want at one shot, remove all entries in all sub dictionaries that have a specific key.

I know I can iterate thru the dictionaries and sub dictionaries, but I also know that Dictionaries have smart ways to do that using predicates and other stuff, but I am not seeing how. I am trying to find that because the method this will run is a little bit tricky and have to do it as fast as possible and I am not sure if normal iteration with loops or whatever will be fast enough...

Any clues? thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a recursive method that doesn't care how many levels deep the target key is.  (haven't tried it) ...

```
- (void)removeKey:(NSString *)keyToRemove fromDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSArray *keys = [dictionary allKeys];

    if ([keys containsObject:keyToRemove]) {
        [dictionary removeObjectForKey:keyToRemove];
    } else {
        for (NSString *key in keys) {
            id value = [dictionary valueForKey:key];
            if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary self]]) {
                [self removeKey:keyToRemove fromDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)value];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this will work. Suppose I do this [self removeKey:@"name" fromDictonary:mainDict]; Your first like you create an array of the keys of the mainDict and the objects I want to delete are not related to those keys. The objects I want to delete are entries of the sub dictionaries that are stored on mainDict...

Comment: I think it works in that case: the first condition will fail, and then we'll find that key in one or more of the sub dictionaries.  The recursive calls on the sub-dictionaries containing the key will do the delete.

Comment: Paste it in and give it a go.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to just iterate through all the subdirectories and remove the appropriate key-value pairs manually. You shouldn't worry if it's fast enough at this point. Rather, create a working implementation and test/measure it. If it's too slow, then you can profile it and come up with ways to improve performance. Premature optimization is a bad thing.

Answer (score -2):

```
NSArray* keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"address", nil]; 
[dics removeObjectsForKeys:keys];  //Or sub dics
```

Comment: I don't get this. WHat is dics? mainDict? Will this remove all objects that has keys like "name" and "address" from all sub dictionaries. Remember that each sub dictionary is inside a dictionary.

Comment: If you want to remove all objects in all subDicts which have key "name" you do :

NSArray* keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", nil]; 
for (id key in mainDict)   {
[[mainDict objectForKey:key] removeObjectsForKeys:keys];  

}